# Creating Drupal custom menu and retrieve item in a template page

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

I would like to create a menu in Drupal backend, a custom menu which have xxx items.

How can I use the Drupal API to retrieve it in a template.tpl.php, and display items?

Comment: Hi mamadou, you might want to be more specific to what it is you would want to be the end result. Why access it from a template.tpl.php file? And what would your menu items do? They can be programmed to call functions that load content, or redirect the user correctly or simply load a form. The answers below are short, but that is because it is hard to understand your real purpose. Sincerest :)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this page at drupal.org: [Menu theming](http://drupal.org/node/988842)

-J

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom menu using [this method](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree_output/6) as well as some related ones. You will need to generate a custom module for your menu. You won't retrieve it in template.tpl.php but rather as a block (by creating a custom module). I would suggest you start there first.

Comment: I use a function similar  $item = menu_tree_page_data('menu-mymenu');

Comment: and I use $tem in my template. May be my question was not clear

Comment: Yes, you will need to look over the documentation of these methods and find which one works best for you. In your new menu module you'll need to call hook_block to return the menu as you need it. You can set the menu to whatever block position you'd like

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Create a custom menu
2. Create a new regions in your template .info file
3. Go to your theme and print the new region where the menu should seen
4. Go to the blogs and activate the new menu in the new region area

Maybe this should work for you.

Comment: am not using it in a bloc. What i wanted, is to get menu object to deal with href, class, link attribute. it is solved with  menu_tree_page_data function